# Fabric JS shapes loaded from SVG have incorrect position

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm trying to add svg to the canvas and scale it. Finally I need to get individual objects. So I use this hideous method to overcome ungroup problem. But in this positions are not correct. Can anyone tell me get absolute positions of a path(left and top).

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var str = '<svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g><ellipse ry="63" rx="63" id="svg_1" cy="225" cx="181" stroke-width="0" fill="#FF0000"/><rect id="svg_2" height="113.99999" width="212.99999" y="169" x="299.00001" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="0" fill="#FF0000"/></g></svg>';
var svg;
fabric.loadSVGFromString(str, function(objects, options) {
  svg = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects,options);
  svg.scaleToHeight(canvas.height);
  canvas.add(svg);
  svg.center();
  canvas.renderAll();
  svg.setCoords();
  var bounds = svg.getObjects();
  console.log(bounds[1]);
  bounds[1].group.setFill('#00000');
  console.log((bounds[1].getLeft() + bounds[1].group.getLeft()));
  console.log(bounds[1].getTop() + bounds[1].group.getTop());
  var items;
  
  fabric.loadSVGFromString(str, function(objects, options) {  
    var group = new fabric.Group(objects,options);
    canvas.add(group);
    group.scaleToHeight(canvas.getHeight());
    group.center();
    canvas.renderAll();
    items = group._objects;
    group._restoreObjectsState();
    canvas.remove(group);    
    canvas.renderAll();
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { 
     items[i].set({
       left:bounds[i].getLeft() + bounds[i].group.getLeft(),
        top:bounds[i].getTop() + bounds[i].group.getTop(),
      });
      canvas.add(items[i]);
      canvas.renderAll();
    }    
    console.log(bounds[1].getBoundingRect());
    console.log(items[1].getBoundingRect());
 }); 
  
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/fabric.js/1.6.0-rc.1/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm answering my question because someone might find it useful. This is how I did it.

1.loaded svg and group using fabric.util.groupSVGElements because its gives most correct positions

2.added svg objects to separate group, so that I can ungroup objects again

3.finally ungrouped object positions are set equal to svg path object positions(I know its silly. But had no other solution)

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var str = '<svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g><ellipse ry="63" rx="63" id="svg_1" cy="225" cx="181" stroke-width="0" fill="#FF0000"/><rect id="svg_2" height="113.99999" width="212.99999" y="169" x="299.00001" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="0" fill="#FF0000"/></g></svg>';
var svg;
fabric.loadSVGFromString(str, function(objects, options) {
  svg = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects,options);
  svg.scaleToHeight(canvas.height);
  canvas.add(svg);
  svg.center();
  canvas.renderAll();
  svg.setCoords();
  var bounds = svg.getObjects();
  console.log(bounds[1]);
  bounds[0].group.setFill('#00000');
  
  fabric.loadSVGFromString(str, function(objects, options) {  
    var group = new fabric.Group(objects,options);
    canvas.add(group);
    group.scaleToHeight(canvas.getHeight());
    canvas.renderAll();
    var items = group._objects;
    group._restoreObjectsState();
    canvas.remove(group);    
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { 
     items[i].set({
       left:svg.getLeft() + bounds[i].getLeft()*svg.getScaleX(),
        top:svg.getTop() + bounds[i].getTop()*svg.getScaleY(),
      });
      canvas.add(items[i]);
    }    
 }); 
  
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/fabric.js/1.6.0-rc.1/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to simulate object movement not to set another top and left values,
it worked for me like this

```
        fabric.loadSVGFromURL(url, function (objects, options) {
        canvas.add.apply(canvas, objects);
    }, function (item, object) {
        object.set('top', object.top + 400);
        object.set('left', object.left + 300);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to call loadSVGFromURL, but don't have to do something else twice. The right code (typescript) should be:

```
      fabric.loadSVGFromURL(url,
        (objects, options) => {
            const svg = fabric.fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
            // canvas scale to svg
            canvas.setWidth(svg.width);
            canvas.setHeight(svg.height);
            //or svg scale to canvas
            //svg.scaleToHeight(canvas.height);

            //Glitch, need to do this twice to make things right
            fabric.loadSVGFromURL(url,
                (objects, options) => {
                    var group = new fabric.Group(objects, options);
                    group.scaleToHeight(canvas.getHeight());
                    var items = group._objects;
                    group._restoreObjectsState();
            
                    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                        canvas.add(items[i]);
                    }
                    
                    canvas.renderAll();
                });

        });
```